# Net Framework 4.8 EF6 EDMX T4 Error _generationEnvironment is NULL

Tags: entity-framework, t4, .net-4.8, edmx, edmx-designer

This started with an EDMX suddenly not generating class files. The .context.cs file contains the class declaration like

```
  public virtual DbSet<myTable> myTable { get; set; }
```

but the actual class files are not being generated. Both .tt files are there & "Run Custom Tool" did not help.

On debugging the Model.tt T4 template this declaration:

```
public StringBuilder GenerationEnvironment { get { return (StringBuilder)_generationEnvironment.GetValue(_instance, null); } }
```

produces

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'"

the _generationEnvironment variable is NULL.

To be sure that database changes were not triggering this I recreated the Model including only a table that had not been modified, but with no improvement.

Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of moving this to Code-First and Core so any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Which VS version exactly?

Comment: thanks, yes looks like a duplicate posted around the same time as mine. I've solved my issue by firing up VS 2019 to do the .EDMX create, but I've noted the workaround now for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. Using Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.6.2

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude:line 1928

Edit: Problem has gone after roll back to 17.5.3

Answer (score 31):

The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.GeneratedTextTransformation.GenerationEnvironment` property access appears to have changed from non public to public in the latest update (ie. 17.6.2)

You can modify the `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude` and `EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude` files in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes` to fix this by changing

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

to

```
_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

EDIT:
Looks like it will be fixed in the next VS version
https://github.com/dotnet/ef6tools/commit/89cd126fa8ebfd40c3b5e781232be940711cf726

Comment: Quick fix. This worked!

Comment: looks like vs2022 17.6.4 have this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I did find the same thing as in the answer in a round-about way - after repairing and then re-installing VS 2022 (pardon, could have mentioned the version) with no effect and being unable to find a way to roll back the Community version, I re-installed VS2019, created the .EDMX model there, no problems.

I'm continuing on in VS2022 now. Hopefully it gets fixed in the next release.