# Error when update model from database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

After I updated the version of Visual Studio from 17.5 to 17.6, I have an issue with the `model.edmx` update from model. When I try to update a `model.edmx` and update entity, I get an error:

> Error
> Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6321A08787B1D16A13C9C3F3FC61C02BFC9187AEBE1F7DFA4EC2C0ABCCB03E262501680949A5260B34002E23AA53CF4409BFEBFDF5677EBCCC3EFBFB2CD6FDD8.GeneratedTextTransformation.DynamicTextTransformation.get_GenerationEnvironment()
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6321A08787B1D16A13C9C3F3FC61C02BFC9187AEBE1F7DFA4EC2C0ABCCB03E262501680949A5260B34002E23AA53CF4409BFEBFDF5677EBCCC3EFBFB2CD6FDD8.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTransformation)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6321A08787B1D16A13C9C3F3FC61C02BFC9187AEBE1F7DFA4EC2C0ABCCB03E262501680949A5260B34002E23AA53CF4409BFEBFDF5677EBCCC3EFBFB2CD6FDD8.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager..ctor(Object textTemplating)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6321A08787B1D16A13C9C3F3FC61C02BFC9187AEBE1F7DFA4EC2C0ABCCB03E262501680949A5260B34002E23AA53CF4409BFEBFDF5677EBCCC3EFBFB2CD6FDD8.GeneratedTextTransformation.EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.Create(Object textTransformation)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating6321A08787B1D16A13C9C3F3FC61C02BFC9187AEBE1F7DFA4EC2C0ABCCB03E262501680949A5260B34002E23AA53CF4409BFEBFDF5677EBCCC3EFBFB2CD6FDD8.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()

EF6 inside `model.tt` doesn't update the existing `entity.cs`, but creates an only empty class named `model.cs`.

I tried to run custom tool but return the same problem.

How I can resolve this?

Thanks for support

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx?force_isolation=true

Comment: I think you need to check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352688/entity-framework-6-t4-code-generation-not-working-in-vs2022

Comment: KeiserSoze provided a very valuable lead, It's a known bug of Visual Studio 2022 v17.6+